# Sitecore OData MaxDepth $expand

Tags: odata, api

I need to retrieve Sitecore item fields and its properties with more than few levels and while running the below query

```
https://sc92instance/sitecore/api/ssc/aggregate/content/Items('76516a9f-203d-4006-b46e-a12fc87d8bc0')?$expand=Children($expand=Children($expand=Children,FieldValues), FieldValues), FieldValues
```

i get error. How can we increase MaxDepth of OData API in sitecore?

```
    {
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. The request includes a $expand path which is too deep. The maximum depth allowed is 2. To increase the limit, set the 'MaxExpansionDepth' property on EnableQueryAttribute or ODataValidationSettings, or set the 'MaxDepth' property in ExpandAttribute."
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your Sitecore version? can you try - `https://sc92instance/sitecore/api/ssc/aggregate/content/Items('76516a9f-203d-4006-b46e-a12fc87d8bc0')/Children?$expand=Fields`. It looks your url string with query is not correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*MaxDepth == 2* is a default value of OData validator. You can override default values by registering your custom validator settings.

1) Add reference to `Microsoft.AspNet.OData` (check corresponding version in your **bin** folder).

[image]

2) Add your custom **ServicesConfigurator** with needed validation parameters:

```
public class ODataServicesConfigurator : IServicesConfigurator
{
    public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        ODataValidationSettings validationSettingFactory(IServiceProvider sp) => new ODataValidationSettings
        {
            MaxAnyAllExpressionDepth = 3,
            MaxExpansionDepth = 3
        };

        serviceCollection.AddSingleton(validationSettingFactory);
    }
}
```

3) Register your ServiceConfigurator in config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <services>
            <configurator type="YourNamespace.ODataServicesConfigurator, YourNamespace"/>
        </services>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```