# Getting error on multiple level children with field values using Sitecore Odata Itemservice

Tags: odata, itemservice

I am trying to get on multiple-level children with field values using Sitecore Odata  Itemservice. I am using the below query:

Query:

```
sitecore/api/ssc/aggregate/content/Items('/sitecore/content/Booked')/children?$expand=FieldValues,Children($expand=FieldValues,Children($expand=FieldValues))
```

But I am getting below error:

```
The query specified in the URI is not valid. The request includes a $expand path which is too deep. The maximum depth allowed is 2. To increase the limit, set the 'MaxExpansionDepth' property on EnableQueryAttribute or ODataValidationSettings, or set the 'MaxDepth' property in ExpandAttribute.
```

I have tried using the solution mentioned below but did not work.

[Sitecore OData MaxDepth $expand](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/25067/sitecore-odata-maxdepth-expand#:%7E:text=The%20maximum%20depth%20allowed%20is,property%20in%20ExpandAttribute.%22%20%7D%20%7D)

I am using `Sitecore 10.3`. Please recommend if any other way we can increase max depth with field values.